# How to get the location of a file located within a Windows application folder

Tags: c#, windows, filepath

What I am trying to do is read data from a CSV file located within a Windows application folder named "Attachments". In a web application you can get the path of the folder using

```
Server.MapPath(@"Attachments/sample.csv");
```

What is the equivalent call from a Windows application?

Below is my code.

```
string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(@"Attachment/sample.csv");

// create new datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// get the column header means first line
string[] temp = str[0].Split(';');

// creates columns of gridview as per the header name
foreach (string t in temp)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(t, typeof(string));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Application Folder could be identified by this enum

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles
```

[MSDN refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

To get a string containing the actual path and the full file name you write

```
string pathToFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
string fullFileName = Path.Combine(pathToFile, @"Attachment\sample.csv");
```

As noted by Cole Johnson in its comment, there is a problem if your hosting operating system is 64bit. In that case there are two application folders. One for 64bit apps and one for 32bit apps.
Using NET4, you could discover the current operating system bitness with the property

```
Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
```

and, if false, use a different enum

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86
```

But after all this, I think you should change something in the architecture of your program.
In Web applications, usually you do not use folders outside the web-root.
But WinForms application has no such limitation and then you may install the CSV files in a different folder (MyDocuments comes to mind) and control the actual location on your hard disk via an option in the configuration file

REMEMBER: The Application Folder requires particular permission to write in (If you save your attachments there this is another reason to choose a different location than the Application Folder)

Comment: or `Enviornment.SpecialForlder.ProgramFilesX86` :)

Comment: Well, syntax error apart :-), you are right, but then we need to know the OS bitness before.

Comment: yep. you can use compiler conditionals though.

Answer (score 2):

Is the path relative to the executable? If so you can use [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) to determine where the program was started, and then combine that with the relative file path to get the full path:

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Attachment\sample.csv");
```

If your app is running as a service or uses ClickOnce deployment this won't work, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with So something like

```
Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Attachment\sample.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Steve beat me to it but yeah, check intellisense for whatever folder you're looking for under :

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.
```

properties

You'll find all kinds of system paths there.